# Image stretching

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want Stretch a image. For that i use sprite. I want stretch sprite & this stretching is may be Circular or curve animation. I don't understand what methode used for that. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with cocos2d I guess you'll be using that. It's really basic to strech an image

```
Sprite *mySprite = [Sprite spriteWithFile:@"mysprite.png"];
mySprite.position = ccp(100, 100);
mySprite.scale = 2.0;
[self addChild:mySprite];
```

If you want to animate it you can use the cocos2d actions or just create your own animation. The example below does a linear animation to 3x original sprite size in 1 second:

```
id action1 = [ScaleTo actionWithDuration:1.0 scale:3.0];    
[mySprite runAction: action1];
```

Answer (score 0):

For manipulating  views and images in general in ways such as streching you can read up on transforms provided by the sdk, you can learn about 2D transforms here http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html and you can extend that further to 3D by manipulating the layers transforms instead of the views transforms. Youll be able to do things such as scaling and rotating and you can define your own transforms as well. This example project http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoveMe/ is a good reference to get started with transforms and animating them.